# How to append a character at the end of each line in unix

Tags: unix, append

I have a large data file and I need to append comma at the end of each line.How can I accomplish this? Thank you.Here is my sample data file as below.

```
1000050G8611
1000200G8611
1000250G8611
1000350G8611
1000375G8611
1000376G9403
1000475G8611
1000500G8611
1000550G8611
1000600G8611
1000610G8611
1000611G0807
1000612G0804
1000614G0802
1000617G8611
1000618G0710
1000619G8611
1000621G8611
1000624G0606
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 awk '{print $0 "," }' file > outFile

 sed 's/$/,/' file > outFile

 sed -i 's/$/,/' file
```

If your sed supports the -i option.

IHTH

Comment: Please fix first line, a `'` is missing after the closing curly brace. After that it works fine. I needed this for expanding my blocked hosts list with `/.*` at the end.

Comment: @Roland : yep, you're right. Thanks, I've fixed this.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick 
`awk '{ print $0 "," }' < inputfile`